# How can I cancel in-flight requests from Mojo::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, promise, user-agent, mojolicious

Let's say I want to cancel an in-flight request of [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/UserAgent)? How can I do that?

Comment: I think for this to be extra useful, you might want to explain what _in-flight_ means in this context. I don't know what it is, and my first thought about the question title was "this is going to be terrible".

Comment: @simbabque: In this case, “in-flight” would mean an HTTP request that has yet to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Demonstration of how to cancel promises

In this example, we create a random Timer promise, and an HTTP Get promise. The first one that wins [rejects](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#reject) the other promise.

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use v5.30;
use experimental 'signatures';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $p1 = Mojo::Promise->timer(rand('0.4') , 'Timeout');
my $p2 = $ua->get_p('https://www.cpanel.net/is_hiring_message_evan_carroll_on_linkedin');

$p1
  ->then(sub ($res) {$p2->reject("\t> reject \$p2"); say $res})
  ->catch(sub ($msg) {say $msg});
$p2
  ->then(sub ($res) {$p1->reject("\t> reject \$p1"); say $res})
  ->catch(sub ($msg) {say $msg});

Mojo::Promise->new->all( $p1, $p2 )->catch(sub{})->wait;
```

Note if the timeout wins, you may get an error event for `Premature connection close` that's what you'd expect. You can see here' we're utilizing [`Mojo::Promise`'s `all`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#all),

> Returns a new `Mojo::Promise` object that **either fulfills when all of the passed `Mojo::Promise` objects have fulfilled or rejects as soon as one of them rejects.** If the returned promise fulfills, it is fulfilled with the values from the fulfilled promises in the same order as the passed promises.

Note, in this case [`race`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#race) is probably more applicable. We wouldn't have to manually reject the other promise, but I wanted to demonstrate rejection in the abstract with `reject` manually.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t actually work.

Consider the following:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use v5.26;
use experimental 'signatures';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $p1 = Mojo::Promise->timer(0.004, 'Timeout');
my $p2 = $ua->get_p('http://www.cpanel.net/is_hiring_message_evan_carroll_on_linkedin');

$p1
  ->then(sub ($res) {$p2->reject("\t> reject \$p2"); say $res})
  ->catch(sub ($msg) {say $msg});
$p2
  ->then(sub ($res) {$p1->reject("\t> reject \$p1"); say $res})
  ->catch(sub ($msg) {say $msg});

Mojo::Promise->new->all( $p1, $p2 )->catch(sub{})->wait;

Mojo::Promise->timer(2)->wait();
```

The changes here are to forgo SSL, to always time out after 0.004 seconds, and to have the event loop wait for an extra 2 seconds.

If you strace the above you’ll see that the request continues.